# Automatic method for placing values of determined column from a SpatialLinesDataFrame near contour lines

Tags: r, plot

I have following vector layer that represents countour lines. With QGIS 3, labels placed near lines (**Layer Properties -> Labels**) were taken from **TEMP_ENE** field in attributes table.

[image]

I would like a similar behavior in R. In this case, I used **rgdal** library to read vector layer as follows:

```
library(rgdal)
isoterma.ene<- readOGR('isotermas_1grado_ene_4326.shp')
isoterma.ene
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 24 
extent      : -71.84042, -68.01765, -41.09749, -36.15523  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 2
names       : ID, TEMP_ENE 
min values  :  0,       12 
max values  :  8,       23
```

I found out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196964/label-lines-in-a-plot) where is used locator() function.

```
coords <- locator()
coords
$`x`
[1] -68.97818
$y
[1] -38.4115
text(x=-68.97818, y=-38.4115,label="23")
```

I tried it out in only one case (value 23) and it worked.

[image]

Is there one method where automatically values in **isoterma.ene$TEMP_ENE** of **SpatialLinesDataFrame** can be placed in these lines?

**Editing Note:**

Based in **mdsummer** answer, following approach works manually:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
isoterma.ene<- readOGR('isotermas_1grado_ene_4326.shp')
plot(isoterma.ene)
```

By using click from raster library:

```
c1<- click(isoterma.ene, id = TRUE, xy = TRUE)
c2<- click(isoterma.ene, id = TRUE, xy = TRUE)
c3<- click(isoterma.ene, id = TRUE, xy = TRUE)
values<- c(c1$TEMP_ENE, rev(c2$TEMP_ENE), rev(c3$TEMP_ENE))
values
[1] 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 14 13
```

It looks as follows:

[image]

By using locator():

```
coor1<- locator()
coor2<- locator()
coor3<- locator()

x<- c(coor1$x, coor2$x, coor3$x)
y<- c(coor1$y, coor2$y, coor3$y)
x
 [1] -69.04728 -69.47572 -69.62774 -69.71067 -69.86269 -70.00090 -70.15292
 [8] -70.24967 -70.38787 -70.66428 -70.89923 -71.12036 -70.12528 -71.17564
y
 [1] -38.50867 -39.16729 -39.53439 -39.73954 -39.86910 -39.96628 -40.13903
 [8] -40.33338 -40.50613 -40.61410 -40.75446 -41.09997 -36.26288 -37.01868
plot(isoterma.ene)
text(x=x, y=y,label=values, cex=0.6)
```

Result is similar as expected; but in manual way:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A very rough start can be made by obtaining the coordinates along the lines and taking a small sample:

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
r <- raster(volcano)
l <- rasterToContour(r)
plot(l)
coords <- as(l, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")
head(coords)
#>       level Lines.NR Lines.ID Line.NR
#> C_1     100        1      C_1       1
#> C_1.1   100        1      C_1       1
#> C_1.2   100        1      C_1       1
#> C_1.3   100        1      C_1       1
#> C_1.4   100        1      C_1       1
#> C_1.5   100        1      C_1       1
coords <- as.data.frame(as(l, "SpatialPointsDataFrame"))
names(coords) ## use this to check the actual column names (may not be coords.x1,coords.x2)
#> [1] "level"     "Lines.NR"  "Lines.ID"  "Line.NR"   "coords.x1" "coords.x2"
text(coords.x2~coords.x1, data = coords[sample(1:nrow(coords), 25),], lab = level, pos = 2, cex = 0.8)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Making them look good as in `contour()` is definitely not easy, but there might be a way to use the logic inside that function.

If you want to use `locator()` itself, try the function `raster::click()` to identify which line, and use that as an index to get the "level" value (TEMP_ENE in your case).

Interactively, I thought this would work but it only returns the values:

```
click(l, id = TRUE, xy = TRUE)
```

so,

```
click(as(l, "SpatialLines"), id = TRUE)
```

to get the value, and locator to get the xy, and manually combine. (If I find a better manual way I'll edit).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, it doesn't work automatically. Labels were placed wrongly. However, I used your manual proposal (see my Editing Note) and it worked but, I'm looking for an automatic method.